# I can only see inner of the character

Tags: mesh, texturing

I found a free rig on the internet and imported the .FBX file. But I can only see the inner of the character from any perspective.

[image]

[The rig](https://www.cgtrader.com/free-3d-models/character/woman/rin-vrc-avatar)

Comment: Hello, welcome to Blender Stackexchange! We would like to help, but you have not given us sufficient information. What have you done to fix this problem? Have you modified your .Blend file in any way? If so, what did you do?

Comment: you probably need to check your Material > Settings > Blend Mode > and switch from Alpha Blend to Opaque

Comment: I didn't modify my blender file in any way. My blend mode is Opaque.

Comment: could you please share the object or at least a part of it? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I already said I use a .FBX file but here you go. https://pasteall.org/blend/1ad08f587ef24876bbce04899ebd2f8b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I select a face of the skirt it will select the material, as you see it is set to *Blend Mode > Alpha Blend*, choose *Opaque* instead:

[image]

Also, you may find some problems with the split normals of an imported FBX, in that case click on the *Clear Custom Split Normals Data* button:

[image]